# openbox: change text and "box" size when switching virtual desktops

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, openbox

when I switch between virtual desktops, openbox shows briefly a "box" with icons of virtual desktops and desktop name (number).

This is ridiculously small on my large monitor, I can barely read the desktop number:
[image]

where in the openbox configuration file (rc.xml) can I change the size of this box and the text size of the virtual desktop number?

I would be happy if it only showed the desktop number in large font size

Answer (score 0):

changing font size in the `ActiveOnScreenDisplay` section to ridiculously large font solves the problem:

```
<font place="ActiveOnScreenDisplay">
<name>sans</name>
<size>48</size>
<weight>bold</weight>
<slant>normal</slant>
</font>
```